# Do areas with depleted resources count for Jim Raynor's victory condition?

Tags: starcraft

I was playing Star Craft: The Board Game recently as Jim Raynor, and a question arose:

Do planet areas with (fully) depleted resources count for Raynor's special victory objective? We ruled it as "no" on the spot, but later I couldn't find anything related in the rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, depleted areas do count. From [the FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/StarCraft/scbw_faq.pdf):

> Q: If an area has been fully depleted of resources, does it still
>   count towards players’ special victory conditions?
>
> A: Yes. For
>   example, Jim Raynor needs to control six areas containing gas and/or
>   minerals; this includes any area that has a printed gas or mineral
>   icon on it.